# postgresql query json for value (instead of key)?

Tags: json, postgresql

Imagine this simple postgresql table ('json_table'):

```
id | data(json)
1  | {"a": 1}
2  | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
3  | {"a": 2}
```

I know it's possible to query for all records having a key 'a': `SELECT * FROM json_table WHERE data ? 'a';`

But I would like to query all records containing a json value '2'. So the result should be this:

```
2  | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
3  | {"a": 2}
```

Is this possible with a 'simple' query like the one mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is an operator which you can use in such a simple query. 
You can achieve this with the query below, though I do not know whether it is the simplest way:

```
select distinct on (id) id, data from (
    select id, data, (json_each(data)).value::text
    from json_table
    ) alias
where value = '2'
```